# java spring boot call function with json output parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have stored function and it returns a value into **json_out**

this is the definition :

```
declare
    request_detail clob := '{ "p_principal":
                                [
                                    {
                                    "p_emp": 200,
                                    "p_request": 23,
                                    "p_date": "23-10-2024",
                                    "p_info": "test"
                                    }
                                ]
                                ,"p_detail":
                                [
                                    {
                                    "p_emp": 200,
                                    "p_date": "23-10-2024",
                                    "p_info": "test"
                                    }
                                ]
                        }';
    json_out                    clob;
begin

json_out := insert_order(request_detail);
dbms_output.put_line(json_out);
end;
```

this is the output :

```
{"p_principal":[{"p_num_generate":15,"p_error":null}]
,"p_detail":[{"p_emp":200,"p_error":null}]}
```

I want to call this function with java spring boot

I try with this code :

```
JSONObject jsonInput = new JSONObject(
                
                
              "{ \"p_principal\":\r\n" + 
              "                                [\r\n" + 
              "                                    {\r\n" + 
              "                                    \"p_emp\": 200,\r\n" + 
              "                                    \"p_request\": 23,\r\n" + 
              "                                 \"p_date\": \"23-10-2024\",\r\n" + 
              "                                    \"p_info\": \"test\"\r\n" + 
              "                                    }\r\n" + 
              "                                ]\r\n" + 
              "                                ,\"p_detail\":\r\n" + 
              "                                [\r\n" + 
              "                                    {\r\n" + 
              "                                    \"p_emp\": 200,\r\n" + 
              "                                    \"p_date\": \"23-10-2024\",\r\n" + 
              "                                    \"p_info\": \"test\"\r\n" + 
              "                                    }\r\n" + 
              "                                ]\r\n" + 
              "                        }"


                );
        
        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("insert_order");

        storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("output", JSONObject.class  , ParameterMode.OUT);

        storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("input", JSONObject.class  , ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedureQuery.setParameter("input", jsonInput);

        storedProcedureQuery.execute();
```

but I have this error

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No @NamedStoredProcedureQuery was found with that name : insert_order
```

can someone help me to solve this problem

Comment: Well ... the error message seems to be clear. You do not have the [`@NamedStoredProcedureQuery `](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F7%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery.html) declaration.